# How to get Foreign key table data based on the status if status is different of a single row in foreign key table laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables with foreign key relationship. Situation is I have a case and a case have many revisions and every revision have its own status. Now what i want is you guys can see `case_id` `1` have three records with different status now i need if single status of child table against `case_id 1` is different i don't want that parent and child except i need all the the data

`PrimaryCaseNo` Model

```
class PrimaryCaseNo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'primary_case_no_migration';
    protected $fillable = ['case_number', 'patient', 'age', 'primary_medical_case_id'];

    public function primaryMedicalCases()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MedicalPrimaryCases::class, 'primary_medical_case_id');
    }

    public function user(){

        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

`MedicalPrimaryCases` Model

```
class MedicalPrimaryCases extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'medical_primary_cases';

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'receive_date', 'impression_particulars', 'nature_of_patient',
        'case_type_particulars', 'priority', 'airway_bill_number', 'description', 'RX_form', 'x_rays_opg', 'x_rays_ceph',
        'file_assessment', 'stl_1', 'stl_2', 'created_by_reference_table', 'deleted_by', 'deleted_by_reference_table',
        'deleted', 'forwarded', 'processed', 'case_id', 'gender', 'doctor', 'impression_type', 'arch_upper', 'arch_lower', 'radio_graphs_opg',
        'radio_graphs_ceph', 'bite', 'impression_workable_upper', 'impression_workable_lower', 'country', 'city',
        'distributor', 'case_type', 'is_deletable', 'is_deleted', 'forwarded_production', 'processed_production', 'processed_by', 'primary_medical_case_id', 'revisions', 'images_at_modification_stage'];

    public function primaryCaseNo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PrimaryCaseNo::class, 'primary_medical_case_id');
    }

}
```

Controller Method

```
public function caseTreatmentSetup(){
  $case_id = array();
        $treatment_setup_cases = MedicalPrimaryCases::select('primary_medical_case_id')->where('status', 'treatment-setup')->get();


        foreach ($treatment_setup_cases as $treatment_setup_case) {
            $case_id[] = $treatment_setup_case->primary_medical_case_id;
        }

        $data['treatment_setup_cases'] = PrimaryCaseNo::with('primaryMedicalCases')->whereIn('id', $case_id)->get();

return view('company.treatment_setup', $data);
}
```

Table  `medical_primary_cases`

```
id      case_id    revison         status
1         1           0           assesemnt
2         1           1           assesment
3         1           2           treatment
4         2           2           assesment
5         3           1           assesmen
```

Table `primary_case_no_migration`

```
id      case_no    patient_name  age
1       12564        abc         78
2       1256         lkj         63
3       125          bdhf        23
```

Result i want Because  case_id holds 2 different status like treatment what i want only assesment if a single row status is different i don't want that.

```
id      case_id    revison         status
4         2           2           assesment
5         3           1           assesment
```

Comment: Please do not ask the same question repeatedly. If the answers provided on the original question do not answer it, edit your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

1. U have set bad keys in relationships methods

```
class PrimaryCaseNo extends Model
{
    public function primaryMedicalCases()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MedicalPrimaryCases::class, 'case_id');
    }
}
```

```
class MedicalPrimaryCases extends Model
{
    public function primaryCaseNo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PrimaryCaseNo::class);
    }
}
```

You need to use eloquent relationships. expl.

```
public function caseTreatmentSetup(PrimaryCaseNo $model){

$data['treatment_setup_cases'] = model->primaryMedicalCases()->where('status', 'treatment-setup')->get();

return view('company.treatment_setup', $data );
}
```

Comment: working it returns empty array()